# How to replace url paramater dynamically in html page with django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Basically, I have a template which have a search form and a table to show the result. The result can be ordered if header column is clicked.
I use `get` method in search form and sort the table's result by **getting the last url**.

views.py

```
if sort_by == "desc":
    order_by = order_by
    sort_by = "asc"
else:
    sort_by = "desc"

url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
if (url != None):
    search_params = {}
    param = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    if (not 'search_button' in request.GET):
        get_request = re.split('&',param.query)
        for single_request in get_request:
            search_query = re.split('=',single_request)
            search_params[search_query[0]] = search_query[1]
        userlist = show_data(order_by,sort_by,search_params)
    else:
        userlist = show_data(order_by, sort_by, request.GET)

def show_data(order_by, sort_by, get_data):
    //the function get the value from db
    return row
```

template.py

```
<table id="user-table">
    <tr>
         <th><a href="?order_by=userId&sort={{sort}}">User id</a></th>
         <th><a href="?order_by=userName&sort={{sort}}">Name</a></th>
         <th><a href="order_by=userAddr&sort={{sort}}">Address</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
{% for item in table_data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ item.userId|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.userName|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.userAddr|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
</tr>
```

The search form able to filter and table result can sort the data. 
Here is the sample url:

if the search button is clicked

```
http://localhost:8080/userlist/?userId=&userName=Jane&userAddr=&search_button=search
```

if the column header is clicked

```
http://localhost:8080/userlist/?order_by=userAddr&sort=asc
```

However, it cannot do sorting again since the the url changed and `search_param` did not get the `userName=Jane`

Is it possible to replace url parameter dynamically in html page like below if the column header is clicked?

```
http://localhost:8080/userlist/?userId=&userName=Jane&userAddr=&search_button=search&order_by=userAddr&sort=desc
```

Thank you in advance. Any suggestion is considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not send your search content with the context. For example:

Let's say you are using this view to render the result:

```
def some_view(request):
    # Do your search mechanism
    search_items = []
    for key, value in search_params.items():
         search_items.append('{}={}'.format(key, value))

    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {
    'user_list': userList,
    'search_param': '&'.join(search_items)
    }, content_type='application/xhtml+xml')
```

In Html:

```
<tr>
         <th><a href="?order_by=userId&sort={{sort}}&{{search_param}}&search_button=search">User id</a></th>
         <th><a href="?order_by=userName&sort={{sort}}&{{search_param}}&search_button=search">Name</a></th>
         <th><a href="order_by=userAddr&sort={{sort}}&{{search_param}}&search_button=search">Address</a></th>
</tr>
```